# ElasticSearch errors on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch installed on Windows (through the MSI package). I installed it to run manually (not as a Window Service). When I run `/bin/ElasticSearch.exe` I am getting:

```
    C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.2.4\bin>elasticsearch.exe 
[2018-05-29T20:01:36,112][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] 
[MSEDGEWIN10] initializing ... [2018-05-29T20:01:36,299][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] 
[MSEDGEWIN10] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Windows 10 (C:)]], net usable_space [59.3gb], net total_space [97.6gb], types [NTFS] [2018-05-29T20:01:36,299][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [MSEDGEWIN10] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true] [2018-05-29T20:01:36,455][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [MSEDGEWIN10] node name [MSEDGEWIN10], node ID [J5yTqffaR9K43tavP87CIQ] [2018-05-29T20:01:36,455][INFO ][o.e.n.Node   ] [MSEDGEWIN10] version[6.2.4], pid[6912], build[ccec39f/2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z], OS[Windows 10/10.0/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_171/25.171-b11] [2018-05-29T20:01:36,455][INFO ][o.e.n.Node   ] [MSEDGEWIN10] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC,
        -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx2048m, -Xms2048m, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.2.4,
        -Des.path.conf=C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [analysis-common] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [ingest-common] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [lang-expression] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [lang-mustache] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [lang-painless] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [mapper-extras] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [parent-join] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [percolator] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [rank-eval] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [reindex] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [repository-url] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [transport-netty4] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] loaded module [tribe] [2018-05-29T20:01:43,752][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MSEDGEWIN10] no plugins loaded [2018-05-29T20:01:54,940][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [MSEDGEWIN10] uncaught exception in thread [main] org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown secure setting [bootstrap.password] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown secure setting [bootstrap.password] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
                at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:346) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:310) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:284) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:331) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:246) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:323) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
                ... 6 more
```

Comment: Might be better to open an issue on https://github.com/elastic/windows-installers. `bootstrap.password` can be set only when installing X-Pack. Please open an issue and follow the details there required e.g. providing the MSI install log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by removing `bootstrap.password` from [the elasticsearch keystore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/secure-settings.html) by navigating to the installation home directory and running

```
bin/elasticsearch-keystore.bat remove bootstrap.password
```

Elasticsearch will now start when running elasticsearch.exe.

Please open an issue on the [Windows Installer GitHub repository](https://github.com/elastic/windows-installers) to discuss, as `bootstrap.password` should only be set in the keystore when X-Pack plugin is installed. I would like to understand more about how you installed and what installation parameters were passed, which would be better to discuss by opening a GitHub issue :)

Comment: thanks Russ..that definitely helped. I've opened the issue on the github repository https://github.com/elastic/windows-installers/issues/200

Answer (score 0):

Out of everything in your log, here is the main error:

`[2018-05-29T20:01:54,940][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [MSEDGEWIN10] uncaught exception in thread [main] org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown secure setting [bootstrap.password] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings.`

Try to start elasticsearch with the following option:

```
bin/elasticsearch -E xpack.security.authc.accept_default_password=false
```

**EDIT**: This didn't help. Did you do clean install or this is re-installation?

Try to setup passwords manually:

```
bin/elasticsearch-keystore add "bootstrap.password"
```

If you do not have any keystore, here is simple how-to:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/secure-settings.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Denis. I tried the suggestion but, same issue. Just one observation, I saw that I'm passing `xpack` parameter in your suggestion however, I did not install XPack option apart of the ElasticSearch GUI installation option. Should I install it?